# facebook - allow lifetime checking of users inbox in our web app in fb php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am doing web app and it should run in cron and checks if facebook user (who authorized this app) has new unread message in his inbox. Then it updates this in our database.

I am using this php script:

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/123456/inbox' ); 
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();   
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  $params = array( 'read_mailbox' );
  $weburl = "http://example.com/cron.php";
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $weburl );
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( $params );
  header("Location: $loginUrl");
}
```

It works when I (user) visit page in browser but it is not working in cron job.

How should I write php instructions for graph api to be able to check any of our users' inbox with this script? (without need of prior login via our page)

Comment: That is of course not possible without the user logging in to your app and granting it permission first.

Comment: My user granted permission for my app.  So do you think it should be available after granted permission or not?

Comment: I am asking if he should log in each time via web to my app or just once? (and then will be my app able to check his inbox in cronjob automatically?)

Comment: You can extend user access tokens to be valid for up to 60 days; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending After that, the user will have to interact with your app again, to create a fresh token.